# how to add date picker to a textbox in a div which has display none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text box in a div whose display is none by default and it will display only when a link is clicked. I tried to add date picker in the textbox inside the hidden div. but i couldn;t do it as the date picker is nt displaying. if code is needed for this tip. i can provide or if more explainations,i can provide that too..please help me how to over come this problem.

Note : the datepicker works in other fields which are visible. but not working with the textbox in the hidden div. Below is the HTML Code of the div and the text field with  nxt_date is the field where i wanna add date picker.

The below div will be the innerHTML of another div when a link is clicked. I have added the JS function below for the link.

This is the link which triggers editor function :

```
<a id='edit' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick='editor();'><b style='color:#689BB9;'>Add Payment</b></a>
```

### JQUERY

```
$(function() {
  $("#nxt_date").date_input();
});
 $.extend(DateInput.DEFAULT_OPTS, {
  stringToDate: function(string) {
    var matches;
    if (matches = string.match(/^(\d{4,4})-(\d{2,2})-(\d{2,2})$/)) {
      return new Date(matches[1], matches[2] - 1, matches[3]);
    } else {
      return null;
    };
  },

  dateToString: function(date) {
    var month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
    var dom = date.getDate().toString();
    if (month.length == 1) month = "0" + month;
    if (dom.length == 1) dom = "0" + dom;
    return  dom+ "-" + month + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  }
});
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
function editor(){
    val=document.getElementById("shwDiv").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("payDiv").innerHTML=val; 
    document.getElementById('net_pay').value='<? echo $paid->net_payable;?>';
    document.getElementById('balance').value='<? echo $paid->balance_amount;?>';


    }
```

### HTML

```
<div id="shwDiv" style="display:none">


    <table style="background-color:#CFE0EA;width:30px;font-size:13px;">

    <tr>
        <td>
            <strong>Netpay:</strong>
 <input type='text' id='netpaid' value = '<? echo$net1; ?>' class= 'box'size="3" readonly />
        </td>
        <td>
            <strong>Paid:</strong> <input type='text' value='<? echo $paid1; ?>' id='paid1' size="3" name='paid1' class="box" readonly />
            <input type='hidden' value='<? echo $paid1; ?>' id='paid1_hidden' size="3"></td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <strong>Balance:</strong>
            <input type='text' value='<? echo $balance1;?>' id='balance1' readonly size="3" class="box"/>
            <input type='hidden' value='<? echo $balance1;?>' id='balance1_hidden' />
        </td>

        <td>
            <strong>Paying&nbsp;now:</strong><br/><input type='text' class="box" id='paying_now' onkeyUp='aa(this.value);' size="3" class="box" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />
        </td>
          <td>
            <strong>Due&nbsp;Date:</strong><input type='text' class="box" id='nxt_date' size="3"  />
        </td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Save" id="save" class="add_btn" onClick="pay_submit();" style="margin-top:10px;height:25px;"/></td> 
    </tr>
</table>


    </p>

    </div>
```

Comment: yes, we will need to see code..

Comment: @Pramodtech Updated with the code now..hope its understandable..thanks

Comment: are u using jquery ui datepicker ?

Comment: @DidierG. am using http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/

Comment: @DidierG. actually am pretty flexible with using any date picker...but the problem is no date picker worked as tried many including jquery ui datepicker in this circumstance

Comment: What do you mean by "works" ? How do you expect a datepicker to be used in an hidden div ? If it is hidden, it's not displayed... :-/

Comment: @ Didier if its hidden it wont display but it will display when i click the edit button. hope that made u understand.

Comment: @Pramodtech will add jquery now

Comment: Is the not working datpicker in the "shwDiv" or "payDiv" ?

Comment: No date pikers are working in shwDiv. when the edit link is clicked the innerHTML of shwDiv will be the innerHTML of payDiv

Comment: I will add a date picker for example and let u know

Comment: This time i tried with http://jonathanleighton.com/projects/date-input/#customisation

Comment: Where is `date1`? Can't see anywhere in your HTML.

Comment: it was my mistake...chaged it to nxt_date few mins ago..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not working because you expect the datepicker to be *copied* (created) when you set the `innerHTML` of the "payDiv" from the "shwDiv".

First of all, there are some inconstancies in your code:

- You tags have several times a `class`attribute: `<input type='text' class="box" id='paying_now' onkeyUp='aa(this.value);' size="3" class="box" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" />`
- Your elements have IDs. If you copy the innerHTML from one div to the other, you will have multiple time the same ID which is not allowed. Use the `name` attribute.

To correct your situation, do this:

You have to initialize again the datePicker instance for the field in the "payDiv" after you set the 'innerHTML'.

```
    function editor() {

    // always you 'var' to declare variables, otherwise they go to the global scope
    var shwDivContent = $('#shwDiv').html(),
        $payDiv = $('#payDiv');

    $payDiv.html(shwDivContent);

    // instanciate the datepicker in the 'payDiv'
    // assuming you have added a 'name' attribute to your field
    $payDiv.find('input[name=nxt_date]').date_input();

    $payDiv.find('input[name=net_pay]').val('<? echo $paid->net_payable;?>');
    $payDiv.find('input[name=balance]').val('<? echo $paid->balance_amount;?>');
}
```

Comment: Well, i don't know what is the datePicker plugin you finally use. Replace `.datePicker()` by the call for your plugin

Comment: Sorry Didier..your ideas worked pretty well. the function is not datepicker its date_input() :) so i tried as such..thanks alot mate